# Call another view with a single exposed filter

Tags: 7, views

I have a page view which works fine for two cases in the exposed filter (say school one and school two).

However, if school three is chosen in the exposed filter, I want another view to be displayed instead of the page view for school one and school two.

I don't mind if it's a block view or page. Just to call another view because its display is different (a summary of school one and two in addition to school three)

@No Sssweat

Comment: You can add JS for this. If exposed filter value is "school three" then display block for another view. Otherwise that view is hidden and show present view.

Comment: Wao! A brilliant idea. But where do i add the JavaScript? In the themes folder or in the created views?

Comment: Add custom js file in themes folder and add path in .info file of theme.

Answer (score 1):

> Wao! A brilliant idea. But where do i add the JavaScript? In the
>   themes folder or in the created views?

In **template.php** located in `sites/all/themes/yourtheme`

Add the following code at the bottom:

```
function yourtheme_views_pre_render(&$view) {

   if ($view->name == 'view_name') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'yourtheme') . '/js/custom.js');
   } 
}
```

- replace **yourtheme** with you actual name of your theme.
- replace **view_name** with your view name.

Also, you'll need to wrap/format your jQuery code like this

/sites/all/themes/yourtheme/js/**custom.js**

```
(function($) {

    //your code goes here

})(jQuery);
```

**PS:** Don't forget to clear the cache to see the changes.